# Как отправить письмо с андроида?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно отправить письмо на почту с андроида, без сторонних приложений.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно использовать [JavaMail API](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/).

Пример [отправки письма](https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/):

```
public class SendMailTLS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "username@gmail.com";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для отправки письма, я  буду использовать существующий аккаунт gmail?

Comment: @Дамир, Для отправки письма нужно пройти авторизацию, следовательно, нужен аккаунт.

Comment: Понял,спасибо за ответ!